# Devise login stopped working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

So logging in to my site has suddenly stopped working... I haven't changed the login form and yet every time I try to log in now it comes back with 'Invalid email or password'. Using a password reset link allows me to change the password and logs me in but if I log out again and try using the password I just set it doesn't work.

I'm absolutely tearing my hair out, I've run out of ideas and it's 2am here so everything's looking pretty bleak. Just some ideas about how I might debug the problem would be great.

Thanks!

---

So, as is often the case, this was just me being an idiot. Note to self: *don't* just casually run `bundle update` without thinking about it and without specifying the actual gem you're interested in, unless you've got a lot of free time and a plentiful supply of Prozac.

When I do get around to deliberately upgrading Devise, this is what I'll need: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Upgrade-to-Devise-2.0

It's great working from home, riding solo on projects, but I do miss being part of a team - just having someone to talk to about issues that crop up really helps and keeps you out of a mental rut. StackOverflow is my team now, you lucky people, I'll make the coffees.

Comment: What is your site written in?  Did you write it yourself?  We need a lot more details before anyone will be able to help much.

Comment: On a side note, many of my problems like this seem to magically work themselves out after a night's sleep. ;)  That's when you notice you were logging into the wrong url...

Comment: You're right about the sleep thing. I woke up this morning feeling slightly more positive and with some ideas for solutions that didn't necessarily involve a bathtub and a toaster :)

Comment: Rock on!  Never have had any luck with a toaster solution myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the password is correct and you can't login then it points to maybe your password salt or password pepper logic having changed?

In the future, you should have a request test on you signup form so you can catch this when your code changes.  Writing a test might help you debug your issue as well.  I recommend Capybara for integration testing.

Comment: You're right, that must be what it is. Although, more than that, it seems there's actually a mismatch between the salt when creating a user and the salt used when authorising them - as I was able to successfully reset my password and still be unable to subsequently log in.

Comment: Anyway, as it turned out, I had 'inadvertently' upgraded Devise from 1.4.7 to 2.0.3. Doh. As soon as I reverted the problem magically went away.

Thanks for your reply and for encouraging me to be less of a cowboy and to write more tests :) That's worth a point quite apart form anything else.