# Cannot Login with Devise after Password Reset

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have a rails 3.2 app and I'm using devise for authentication.

I recently went to test to the password reset functionality and noticed that while the reset password appears to work (the app lets you reset the password and then logs you in) if I log out of the app and then try to log in again I cannot log in. The app reports that I have an invalid email/password combo.

I've checked that the DB is getting updated with and the reset_password_[token/sent_at] fields are getting updated correctly. The object (User object) is getting updated as well according to the timestamp. BUT, I can no longer log in with the password I just used.

I'm not sure what might be causing this. I've seen some one other related [one other related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9346053/devise-login-stopped-working) about this same issue but it doesn't really have an answer - only a clue: the salt/pepper logic.

What would allow the user to change their password but not log in again? Any ideas?

Current ENV:
Rails 3.2
Devise 2.2.4
Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: Are you able to log in with the old password? Sorry, I feel the urge to say write your own auth. Devise requires more work than it's worth.

Comment: The original and new password does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. Another developer on my team had added a before_validation callback on the User object that was generating a random password for new users (because of a new simpler sign up process) and they forgot to write a test for password updating. Therefore, when the password was updated, the before_validation callback was being called and a new random password was being generated. Fixed that and wrote some tests and now its working as it should.

Comment: I'd accept my own answer, but I can't for two days. I'll return and do it then ...